# Recoll. What is the difference between "mime" and "rclcat"?

Tags: mime-type, recoll

I'm trying to figure out  what is the difference in Recoll between "mime", "rclcat" operators. As I see they both define the type: "rclcat:text" and "mime:text".

Answer (score 1):

mime: is a specific MIME type like text/plain or application/pdf

rclcat: refers to a grouping of MIME types, e.g. in 'text', text/plain but also application/msword, application/pdf etc. These groups are defined in the mimeconf configuration file.

https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/usermanual/webhelp/docs/RCL.INSTALL.CONFIG.MIMECONF.html